# String attribute set in init method always returns empty string

Tags: nearprotocol

I have the following struct with impl:

```rust
#[near_bindgen]
#[derive(Default, Serialize, Deserialize, BorshDeserialize, BorshSerialize, Debug)]
pub struct MyStruct {
    owner: String
}

#[near_bindgen(init => new)]
impl MyStruct {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
             owner: "bob".to_string()
        }
    }

    fn get_owner(&self) -> String {
         return self.owner;
    }
}
```

Then I deploy the contract using `near deploy my_contract --masterAccount myAccount`

If I call get_owner using near-shell: `near call my_contract get_owner --accountId=myAccount` It always returns `""` instead of the expected `"bob"`.

It seems like the new method might not get called on deployment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initializer doesn't automatically get called on deploy. `deploy` just deploys the code and doesn't call anything on the contract. We should probably add a new method to shell, that does `deploy_and_call`. But for now just call `new` manually.

The reason why we don't initialize automatically is that `initializer` might take additional arguments. You can pass an owner to `new` method. Here is an example how to use initializer with custom arguments and as well as how to make sure a contract can't be called without initialization:

```rust
#[near_bindgen]
#[derive(BorshDeserialize, BorshSerialize)]
pub struct FunToken {
    /// AccountID -> Account details.
    pub accounts: Map<AccountId, Account>,

    /// Total supply of the all token.
    pub total_supply: Balance,
}

impl Default for FunToken {
    fn default() -> Self {
        env::panic(b"Not initialized");
        unreachable!();
    }
}

#[near_bindgen(init => new)]
impl FunToken {
    pub fn new(owner_id: AccountId, total_supply: Balance) -> Self {
        let mut ft = Self { accounts: Map::new(b"a".to_vec()), total_supply };
        let mut account = ft.get_account(&owner_id);
        account.balance = total_supply;
        ft.accounts.insert(&owner_id, &account);
        ft
    }
}
```

From here: https://github.com/nearprotocol/near-bindgen/blob/master/examples/fun-token/src/lib.rs#L52-L77

Basically it panics during Default call, so non initialized contract can't be called.

Answer (score 2):

Initializer functions are usually used when you need to parametrize the initialization of the contract. If there are no parameters then just implement `Default` trait:

```rust
impl Default for MyStruct {
  fn default() -> Self {
    Self {
      owner: "bob".to_string()
    }
}}
```